# Windows Azure free trial hosting

Tags: azure

I have created one windows azure free account for checking cloud hosing. I configured IIS and database on the server using remote desktop. after that when i try to access this test application using http://xyz.cloudapp.net:81/logon.apsx, but logon page not loading. If i try it in remote desktop of virtual machine, its working fine.

Comment: Have you configured firewall rules properly and opened up port 81? In the Azure Portal that would be under endpoint configuration.

Comment: Yes, added http and public and private port set to 81, even  http://xyz.cloudapp.net is not accessible in remote desktop machine also. I have created virtual machine, cloud service and app services